# Why are the backslash and semicolon required with the find command's -exec option?

Tags: linux, command, find, backslash

I have begun to combine different commands in the linux terminal. I am wondering why the backslash and semicolon are required for a command such as:

```
find ./ -name 'blabla' -exec cp {} ./test \;
```

when a simple cp command is simply:

```
cp randomfile ./test
```

without the `\;`

Are they to clearly indicate the end of a command, or is it simply required in the documentation? What is the underlying principle?

Comment: A `;` on it's own would end the command. By using `\;`, a literal `;` is being passed as a parameter to `find`.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The backslash before the semicolon is used, because `;` is one of list operators (or `&&`, `||`) for separating shell commands. In example:

```
command1; command2
```

The `find` utility is using `;` or `+` to terminate the shell commands invoked by `-exec`.

So to avoid special shell characters from interpretation, they need to be escaped with a backslash to remove any special meaning for the next character read and for line  continuation.

Therefore the following example syntax is allowed for `find` command:

```
find . -exec echo {} \;
find . -exec echo {} ';'
find . -exec echo {} ";"
find . -exec echo {} \+
find . -exec echo {} +
```

See also:

- [Using semicolon (;) vs plus (+) with exec in find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085156/using-semicolon-vs-plus-with-exec-in-find)
- [Simple unix command, what is the {} and \; for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447048/simple-unix-command-what-is-the-and-for)

Answer (score 60):

from "man find":

> All following
>             arguments to find are taken to be arguments to the command until
>             an  argument  consisting of ';' is encountered.

find needs to know when the arguments of exec are terminated. It is natural to terminate a shell command with ; because also the shell uses this character. For the very same reason such a character must be escaped when inserted through the shell.