# Linux: find a file in a directory, backup it with another name, replace it

Tags: linux, bash

In Linux I'm trying to find a file in a directory, backup it with another name and, then, replace it with another one.

I tried the first two actions with these commands

```
find foldername -name filename.html; -exec sed -i .bak;
```

but it's says

> bash: -exec: command not found

Comment: Why do you put a semicolon after the file name? A semicolon tells bash that one command ended and another is about to start, and `-exec` is not a command bash recognizes. If you really need the semicolon there, you have to put the file name in quotes, or escape it. [See also this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913198/why-are-the-backslash-and-semicolon-required-with-the-find-commands-exec-optio).

Comment: Oh, right! I tried semicolon after I tried pipe to connect the two commands :)

Comment: `;` separates two commands. It makes `bash` search the `-exec` program and `bash` fails (with the error message you posted). Don't put `;` in the command line unless you need to write two commands (not here). The command you put after `-exec` needs to be terminated with `\;`. This tells `find` where the arguments of `-exec` end and allows it to look for more options in the rest of the command line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursively rename files using find and sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793892/recursively-rename-files-using-find-and-sed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
find foldername -name filename.html -exec cp -vp {}{,.bak} \; -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;
```

This uses `find`'s `exec` option like it looks like you tried to use. Then `cp` copies the file (specified with `{}`) and appends `.bak` to the copy and preserves what it can with the `p` option:

> preserve the specified attributes (default:
>                 mode,ownership,timestamps), if possible additional attributes:
>                 context, links, xattr, all

This leaves the original file in place as well.

Comment: thanks. This is working as expected.
Can you tell me how to replace the original file with another one?

Comment: What do you mean by "with another one"? Are you talking about a blank file? Or something else?

Comment: I want to replace it with a new file with the same name.

Comment: You can add an additional `exec` that truncates the original file. See my updated answer

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following:

```
find . -name 'FILE_PATTERN_HERE' | xargs -I file_name cp file_name file_name.bkp
```

You can pipe the output of `find` command to `cp` using `xargs`. Here `file_name` acts as the output of `find`.

**Example**

```
find . -name 'logback.xml*'
```

Output:

```
./logback.xml
./apache-cassandra-3.11.1/conf/logback.xml
```

After running the command

```
find . -name 'logback.xml*' | xargs -I file_name cp file_name file_name.bkp
find . -name 'logback.xml*'
```

Output:

```
./logback.xml
./apache-cassandra-3.11.1/conf/logback.xml
./apache-cassandra-3.11.1/conf/logback.xml.bkp
./logback.xml.bkp
```

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: sorry I don't know why but there isn't the backup copy in the folder

Comment: find antifurti -name 'informativa.html' | xargs -I informativa.html cp informativa.html informativa_201800608.html

Comment: Try this `find antifurti -name 'informativa.html' | xargs -I file_name cp file_name file_name.bkp`