# Using AppleScript or Automator to find and copy images with a string of text from a text file and copy images to another folder

Tags: bash, terminal, applescript, automator

Here is what I'm trying to do:

-Search for the first item on the austinproductlist.txt file within a folder and all its sub folders

-If the item is found, copy it to the folder on the desktop labeled as "target"

-repeat for every item listed in the .txt file

My attempt using the terminal:

```
$for i in `cat ~/Desktop/austinproductlist.txt’find ~/desktop/AustinWebImages -type f -name "$i" -exec cp "{}" ~/Desktop/target ;
```

Response:
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `find'

My AppleScript attempt:

I think the issue is that the command is look for the exact file name but what I need to search for is a string within the file name. If the filename contains that string, I would like to copy it to the folder "target".

Here's a screen shot of my automator attempt:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are only two problems with your script:

1) Your `for` loop needs `do` and `done`.

2) The `-exec` action needs a backslash at the end (`\`)

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `~/Desktop/austinproductlist.txt`;
  do find ~/desktop/AustinWebImages -type f -name "$i" -exec cp "{}" target \;
done
```

In case you're wondering about the trailing backslash; the `-exec` action takes each command up until the `;` which needs to be escaped because shell uses it also, and would otherwise terminate the `find` command.

[Why are the backslash and semicolon required with the find command's -exec option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913198/why-are-the-backslash-and-semicolon-required-with-the-find-commands-exec-optio)

Comment: for some reason the it is now giving me a permission denied for my .txt file... just trying to figure that out now

Comment: Can you show the output of `ls -l Desktop/austinproductlist.txt`?

Comment: I'm looking for the 10-symbol string showing showing permission rights for that file :).

Comment: iMac:~ azfour$ ls -l Desktop/austinproductlist.txt
-rw-r--r--@ 1 azfour  staff  112 17 Dec 17:12 Desktop/austinproductlist.txt

Comment: I have solved the permissions issue but its not moving the images. I think it may be because the text file only contains a string within the images name and not the entire image name.

Comment: If you format your input text file one filename per row, with extensions, it will work :).