# What does {} \; mean

Tags: find

I found the following very useful command on this site:

```
find -type f -name '*.bz2' -execdir bzgrep "pattern" {} \;
```

But I don't understand what the {} \; means, can anyone explain?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple unix command, what is the {} and \; for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447048/simple-unix-command-what-is-the-and-for)

Answer (score 2):

Placeholders in `find`.

`{}` denotes 'whatever you found'.

`;` means end of statement. The `\` lets `find` see it, without the shell interpolating it.

It's often considered sensible to use `'{}'` (e.g. with single quotes) because the shell *will* interpolate `{}`.

Comment: What do you mean by `the shell will interpolate {}`? Which `shell`?

Comment: Without quotes, a filename with a space of special character might do something odd.

Comment: The quotes will get processed before `find`. The only way it would matter would be if some shell considered `{}` to mean something special (in which case `''` would likely preserve the literal `{}`), but I'm not aware of any that do.

Answer (score 2):

```
-execdir bzgrep "pattern" {} \;
  ^      ^        ^       ^  ^^
  |      |        |       |  ||
  |      |        |       |  |end of the execdir flag
  |      |        |       |  |
  |      |        |       |  shell escape
  |      |        |       |
  |      |        |       2. argument to bzgrep
  |      |        |       {} is substituted with the current filename
  |      |       1. argument to bzgrep
  |      |
  |    the command to run
execute a command
```

i.e. for each file that `find` finds, it runs bzgrep where `{}` is substituted with the file name.

The `;` is needed to end the -execdir, so you can e.g. have other flags to the find command after it. the `\` is used to escape the `;`, since a `;` on the shell would otherwise be interpreted as a command separator (as in e.g. the oneline `cd /etc ; ls -l`). Single quoting the ; would also work, `';'` instead of `\;` - at least in bash.

Or as the manpage sayes:

> -exec command ;
>
> Execute command;  All following  arguments to find are taken to
> be arguments to the command
> until an argument consisting of  ‘;’  is  encountered.   The  string
> ‘{}’  is replaced  by the current file name being processed

Answer (score 1):

{} is the filename find found ant to substituted in the exec(dir) command.
\; is end of command given after execdir. You need the backslash, since it is not used to show the end of the complete unix command (find).